# Can not request query in navigation window phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I have a `usercontrol` in page `page1.xaml` and navigation to `page2.xaml`.

Code in `usercontrol` is :

```
private void lbDataTopic_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/PageTest.xaml?p=2"), UriKind.Relative));
}
```

I want to request query string `p` in `page2.xaml`

```
public PageTest()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            if (!NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("p"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(NavigationContext.QueryString["p"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But when I'm running program, it displays an error

> System.nullrefereceException : Object reference is not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 0):

You should get QueryString in OnNavigatedTo method, just like:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("p"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(NavigationContext.QueryString["p"]);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
    }
```